# How to use FileObserver for System files [Android]

Tags: android

I wan to monitor changes in android system file
`"/sys/class/net/eth0/operstate"` for monitoring ethernet state.

I have written an File Observer class but i am not getting any events in 
`public void onEvent(int event, String path)` call back function.

Do we need any special type of permissions for observing android system files?
Do i need to run my APK as root.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't use for observing Android system files, we need root permissions for this.

Comment: Suppose device is rooted. Then can one application monitor other applications app section ie Apps internal memory ?